# change data value in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm starting with vue and I'm making a test to change a value when a button is clicked , but is not working

```
    <template>
  <div class="row">
    {{ show }}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="change_show">Good</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Bad</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Food</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "buttons",
  data(){
    return{
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods:{
    change_show(event){
      show = !show;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined
```

How I can access to the variables and change it?

Comment: place ```show``` within the return object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your variable incorrectly, you should add `show` (and all your reactive variables) in the return:

```js
data(){
  return{
    show: true
  };
},
```

Comment: I made show changes on the question but is still not working

Comment: @dr_fg2 try to add `this` keyword: `this.show = !this.show;`